# Fullpage.js v3 - Slide reset bug

Tags: fullpage.js

I have updated to v3 with all v3 plugins. i have been informed there is  a bug with the reset slider plugin. This site also uses parallax plugin and scrolloverflow plugin. all latest versions.

The bug:

Say your on section 2, you scroll to section 2 slide 2. Then slide up to section 1, then slide back down to section 2. then slide back to section 2 slide 2. The background will now be 75% offset and out of place.

https://www.ahimsainvestments.com

Fault goes if plugin is disabled.

I am on the road atm. can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Your linked site is not using resetSliders.

Comment: Sorry was disabled was being tested. no workaround was found though. resetsliders Enabled gain. Thank you for the support